# How to do regex replacement in Python using dictionary values, where the key is another matched object from the same string

Tags: python, regex, search, dictionary, replace

My regex needs to match two words in a sentence, but only the second word needs to be replaced. The first word is actually a key to a dictionary where the substitute for the second word is fetched. In PERL it would look something like:

```
$sentence = "Tom's boat is blue";
my %mydict = {}; # some key-pair values for name => color
$sentence =~ s/(\S+)'s boat is (\w+)/$1's boat is actually $mydict{$1}/;
print $sentence;
```

How can this be done in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
>>> sentence = "Tom's boat is blue"
>>> mydict = { 'Tom': 'green' }
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("(\S+)'s boat is (\w+)", lambda m: "{}'s boat is actually {}".format(m.group(1), mydict[m.group(1)]), sentence)
"Tom's boat is actually green"
>>>
```

though it would look better with the lambda extracted to a named function.

Comment: It worked perfectly, but I wonder why it is so much less intuitive than in Perl, quite contrary to my experience with Python so far.